# How do I compute E(Y|Y≠0) from a joint normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

Suppose we have a joint normal distribution: $X\sim N(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$ and $Y^*\sim N(\mu_{Y^*},\sigma_{Y^*}^2)$, and the covariance $cov(X,Y^*)=\rho\sigma_X\sigma_{Y^*}$. Define $Y\equiv Y^*$ if $Y^*>X$ and 0 if otherwise.

How do I compute $E(Y|Y\neq 0)$?

Comment: Anyway, have you tried using what you learnt from [your previous question](/q/4789582/)?

Comment: @user10354138 It's given in the variance-covariance matrix of $X,Y^*$. And yes - I have.

Comment: @user10354138 I said $X,Y^*$ are joint normal. It's given in a variance-covariance matrix. I couldn't type in the {bmatrix} here on stack overflow so I wrote it like this.

Comment: @user10354138 It's a typo. I've fixed it. And yes - I have read what I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x,y^*)$ denote the joint density of $X$ and $Y^*$. Define $I_{(Y^*>X)}$ to be an indicator random variable such that it equals one when $Y^*>X$ and zero otherwise.

First, we have
$$
E(Y\mid Y\neq 0) = E(Y^*\mid Y^*>X)=E(Y^*\mid I_{(Y^*>X)}=1).
$$
Second, we have
$$
P(I_{(Y^*>X)}=1)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{y^*>x} f(x,y^*)dy^*dx.
$$
and
$$
P(Y^*=y^*,I_{(Y^*>X)}=1)=\int_{y^*>x} f(x,y^*)dx.
$$
Third, the expectation can be calculated by
\begin{equation}\label{eq_1}
\frac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^*\cdot\int_{y^*>x} f(x,y^*)dx dy^*}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{y^*>x} f(x,y^*)dxdy^*}.
\end{equation}

Next, by the property of conditional normal distribution,
$$f(x, y^*) = f(x\mid y^*) \cdot f(y^*),$$
where $f(x\mid y^*)$ is the density of $\mathcal{N}\left(\mu_X+\frac{\sigma_{X}}{\sigma_{Y^*}} \rho\left(y^*-\mu_{Y^*}\right),\left(1-\rho^2\right) \sigma_{X}^2\right)$ and $f(y^*)$ is the density of $Y^*$.

Therefore,
$$
\int_{y^*>x} f(x,y^*)dx  = \int_{y^*>x} f(x\mid y^*) f(y^*)dx =
CDF_{x\mid y^*}(y^*)\cdot f(y^*),
$$
where $CDF_{x\mid y^*}$ is the CDF of $\mathcal{N}\left(\mu_X+\frac{\sigma_{X}}{\sigma_{Y^*}} \rho\left(y^*-\mu_{Y^*}\right),\left(1-\rho^2\right) \sigma_{X}^2\right)$.

Finally,
$$\frac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^*\cdot\int_{y^*>x} f(x,y^*)dx dy^*}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{y^*>x} f(x,y^*)dxdy^*}
=
\frac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^*\cdot CDF_{x\mid y^*}(y^*)\cdot f(y^*) dy^*}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty CDF_{x\mid y^*}(y^*)\cdot f(y^*)dy^*},
$$
where recall that $f(y^*)$ is the density of $\mathcal{N}\left(\mu_{Y^*}, \sigma_{Y^*}^2\right)$.

Comment: But how do I compute the integrals? I want to express it using $\mu_X,\mu_{Y^*},\rho,\sigma_X,\sigma_Y$, and the PDF, CDF of standard normal.

Comment: @AcceptCookies I have made an attempt and added more details.

Comment: But how to express it in terms of standard normal PDF and CDF? Now we're expressing in terms of the CDF of $X|Y^*$.

Comment: @AcceptCookies $CDF_{x \mid y^*}\left(y^*\right) = \Phi((y^*-\mu_{x \mid y^*})/\sigma_{x \mid y^*})$, where $\Phi$ is the CDF of $\mathcal N(0,1)$, $\mu_{x \mid y^*} = \mu_X+\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_{Y^*}} \rho\left(a-\mu_{Y^*}\right)$ and $\sigma_{x \mid y^*} = \sqrt{\left(1-\rho^2\right) }\sigma_X$.

Comment: @AcceptCookies You may also change the variable in the integrals $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y^* \cdot C D F_{x \mid y^*}\left(y^*\right) \cdot f\left(y^*\right) d y^*$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} C D F_{x \mid y^*}\left(y^*\right) \cdot f\left(y^*\right) d y^*$ by $z=(y^*-\mu_{Y^*}) / \sigma_{Y^*}$ (remember to multiply the Jaccobian $\sigma_{Y^*}$), and this will transform $f(y^*)$ to the density of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: what is the $a$ in the CDF of $x|y^*$?

Comment: @AcceptCookies Sorry, it is a typo. It should be $y^*$ instead (recall that it is the density of $X$ conditional on $Y^*=y^*$).